# Split numbers from String array in java

Tags: java, regex, string

```
String Equation = input.nextLine();
String[] number = Equation.split("\d+");
```

I want to split all digits come into string and dump into number. How'd do it?

like Equation is : 2x^4 - 45y^4

it should be dumped in number on index as : {2, 4 , 45, 4};

Comment: There's no escape sequence `\d` in java. Your code won't ocmpile.

Comment: @RaptorDotCpp it will not compile.

Comment: So how it can be done. how'd split them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I'd do is `String.replaceAll` all non-digits with whitespace.  Then `String.split` by whitespace.

```
package com.sandbox;


import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sandbox {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "2x^4 - 45y^4";
        input = input.replaceAll("\\D", " ");
        String[] parts = input.split("\\W+");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
    }
}
```

This will print "[2, 4, 45, 4]"

---

Now that I understand @RohitJain's answer, it seems I'm including an unnecessary step.  I guess I'll leave this here anyway since it does work, but I recommend his solution.  His solution splits on all non digits.  Since `split` excludes the delimiter, this also removes the non-digits.

Answer (score 8):

You can split on one or more non-digit characters - `\\D+`:

```
String[] number = equation.split("\\D+");
```

While working with Java regex, you need to double escape the `\d`, `\D`, so on. And please follow Java naming convention. Your variable should be named `equation`, not `Equation`.